# 3D Game Engine, Get absolute transform

Tags: 3d, game-engine, rotational-matrices

I have a parent scene node in my engine, and a child. child's transform(position, rotation and scale) is relative to the parent.
Now I want to know the child's absolute transform. I mean the child's relative transform to the main coordinates.
Any ideas?
Edit: The problem is that I don't store matrices in a scene node. I only have 3 vectors. Position, Rotation and Scale.

Comment: Multiply all your transform matrixes? (parents, ..., sub-parents, children)

Comment: A function that converts pos/rot/scale to a matrix is a necessity in any game engine. Storing/caching said matrix is often a good idea for performance reasons.

Comment: @Macke: Then how do I convert a vector to a matrix or convert a matrix to a vector?

Comment: @Kia.celever: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix (or just f-in google it, every 3d graphics engine ever made has code for the same)

Comment: A lot of engines don't even provide their own code, because every graphics math library around has matrix creation functions. For example, [D3DX has an entire family of functions to build various matrices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172972(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to walk down the tree and multiply each matrix along the way, from the scene root to the final object. The resulting matrix will be the absolute transforms.